# InvalidArgumentException: Class "\Drupal does not exist. Drupal 9.5.2

Tags: class, module, drupal, path, controller

I'm trying to learn how to develop modules and I'm having controller path problems

`InvalidArgumentException: Class "\Drupal\new_module\Controller\NewModuleController" does not exist. in Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ClassResolver->getInstanceFromDefinition() (line 24 of core\lib\Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ClassResolver.php).`

web\modules\custom\new_module\new_module.info.yml:

```
name: New Module
description: My first module custom
package: New Modules
type: module
core: 8.x
core_version_requirement: ^8 || ^9
```

web\modules\custom\new_module\new_module.routing.yml:

```
new_module.content:
  path: '/admin/config/new-mogule-first'
  defaults:
    _title: 'New Module'
    _controller: '\Drupal\new_module\Controller\NewModuleController::content'
  requirements: 
    _permission: 'access content'
```

web\modules\custom\new_module\src\Controller\NewModuleController.php:

```
<?php
    namespace Drupal\new_module\Controller;
    use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

    class NewModuleController extends ControllerBase {
        public function content(){
            return array(
                '#type'=> 'markup',
                '#markup' => $this->t('Hola, prueba'),
            );
        }

    }
?>
```

drush status:

Drupal version   : 9.5.2
Site URI         : http://default
DB driver        : mysql
DB hostname      : localhost
DB port          : 3306
DB username      : root
DB name          : drupasl_new_module
Database         : Connected
Drupal bootstrap : Successful
Default theme    : olivero
Admin theme      : claro
PHP binary       : C:/xampp/php/php.exe
PHP config       : C:/xampp/php/php.ini
PHP OS           : WINNT
PHP version      : 8.1.12
Drush script     : C:/xampp/htdocs/drupal/new_module/vendor/bin/drush
Drush version    : 11.4.0
Drush temp       : C:/Users/54113/AppData/Local/Temp
Drush configs    : C:/xampp/htdocs/drupal/new_module/vendor/drush/drush/drus
h.yml
Install profile  : standard
Drupal root      : C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\new_module/web
Site path        : sites/default
Files, Public    : sites/default/files
Files, Temp      : C:\xampp\tmp

I also generated a test module with the drush, it gives the same error

Comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/218080/invalidargumentexception-class-not-found-in-custom-module/316099#316099

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should clear the cache from (admin/config/development/performance) in order to reset all database controller stored routes.

It fixes everything in the most of situations.

Answer (score 0):

For configuration form with endpoints starting with `/admin` you need to use `configFormBase` class.

Plain routing should not have `/admin` endpoints